# OmniSharp: Could not load file or assembly System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.6.3.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

Please help me out, I'm ripping out my hair over here. I start up VS Code and I get this. What is going on? I just want to get my work done.

I tried looking it up but I don't understand anything, it was working fine some days ago.

I have no other extensions installed, just .NET 5.0.103 and Unity.

> The project system 'OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem' threw exception
> during initialization. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load
> file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.6.3.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> dependencies. The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070570) File name:
> 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.6.3.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'    at
> OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager..ctor(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
> MSBuildOptions options, IEventEmitter eventEmitter, IFileSystemWatcher
> fileSystemWatcher, MetadataFileReferenceCache
> metadataFileReferenceCache, PackageDependencyChecker
> packageDependencyChecker, ProjectLoader projectLoader,
> OmniSharpWorkspace workspace, IAnalyzerAssemblyLoader
> analyzerAssemblyLoader, ImmutableArray 1 eventSinks, DotNetInfo
> dotNetInfo)    at
> OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem.Initalize(IConfiguration
> configuration) in D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectSystem.cs:line
> 108    at OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer.Initialize(IServiceProvider
> serviceProvider, CompositionHost compositionHost) in
> D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Host\WorkspaceInitializer.cs:line 54
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
> not set to an instance of an object.    at
> OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.DisposeCore(Boolean disposing) in
> D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.MSBuild\ProjectManager.cs:line 156    at
> OmniSharp.Utilities.DisposableObject.Finalize() in
> D:\a\1\s\src\OmniSharp.Shared\Utilities\DisposableObject.cs:line 13

Thanks!

Comment: When deailing with situations like this, always look for the first error or exception. In your case: "System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow". There are a lot of results for this which sound very promissing.

Answer (score 1):

Eh, whatever. Reinstalled everything according to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity for the third time this month.

Comment: I have the same issue. But I have a lot of dependencies and it would take a whole week to install and configure all the VS Code extensions again. So, I need another solution.